# Find whether length of a string in json array exceeds certain limit

Tags: json, unix, sed, jq

I have a file which contains many json arrays. I need to find if length of any value in any of the array exceeds a limit, say 1000. If it exceeds I have to trim the length of that particular value. Post that file will be fed to downstream application. What is the best possible solution to be implemented in shell scripting. Tried jq and sed but that doesn't seem to work. Maybe I haven't explored them completely. Any suggestion on this use case will be highly appreciated!

Comment: If you add an example of the input and expected output, you might get more upvotes!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the originally posted question is rather vague on a number of points, so I'll first focus on determining whether an arbitrary JSON document has a string value (excluding key names) that exceeds a certain given size.

To find the maximum of a stream of numbers, we can write:

```
def max(stream): reduce stream as $s (null;
  if $s > . then $s else . end);
```

Let us suppose the above def, together with the following line, is in a file named max.jq:

```
max( .. | strings | length) > $mx
```

Then we could find the answer by running a command such as:

```
jq --argjson mx 4 -f max.jq INPUT.json
```

### A shorter but possibly less space-efficient answer

```
jq --argjson mx 4 '[..|strings|length]|max > $mx' INPUT.json
```

### Variants

There are many possible variants, e.g. you might want to arrange things so that jq returns a suitable return code rather than emitting a boolean value.

### Truncating long strings

To truncate strings longer than a given length, say $mx, you could use `walk/1`, like so:

```
walk(if type == "string" and length > $mx
     then .[:$mx] else . end)
```